Splitting Core Data Model Configurations in production app
I have a production app using Default configuration which is used with CloudKit. I now want to introduce new entities which will not be synced with iCloud. I understand that two new configurations will need to be created (one local and one iCloud) and entities moved under the newly created configs. I will be using the following setup:
init { 
    persistentContainer = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MockDataModel")

let defaultDirectory = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.defaultDirectoryURL()

let localStore = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: defaultDirectory.appending(path: "local.sqlite")) localStore.configuration = "Local" 

let cloudStore = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: defaultDirectory.appending(path: "cloud.sqlite")) cloudStore.configuration = "Cloud" cloudStore.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "iCloud.com.mockContent")

persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions = [ localStore, cloudStore ]

persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { _, _ in }

}

Are there any implications in creating new configurations for production app where users have data stored in iCloud? Will the migration be handled automatically?

The only automatic migration is “lightweight migration”
